# How do I make the background image cover the div, and not the body?

Tags: css

I am trying to make the background image be positioned to the bottom left of a div and cover the entire div, without distorting it's ratio.

Whenever I use

```
background:url("img.jpg") no-repeat left bottom fixed;
```

it goes to the left of the body and the bottom of the body, not the div. How do I get it to use the div as the frame of reference and not the body?

Fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/UFpYd/3/

Comment: Wrong jsfield url? I don't see any background url there

Comment: Yea, it's not the right fiddle. It doesnt show any interesting even if filling the divs with content.

Comment: Here's the right fiddle ladies http://jsfiddle.net/UFpYd/3/

Comment: Your fiddle does not match your code. In your question you use `left bottom` but in your fiddle you use `center top` for positioning.

Comment: I can't honestly tell what you're really after. What should the end result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
background: url('img.jpg') no-repeat scroll center top/cover transparent;
```

EDIT:-

After watching your JSFiddle you may try this:

```
background: url('img.jpg') no-repeat left bottom;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UFpYd/14/)

Comment: @ScottS:- Yes it looks like but initially the JSFIDDLE was not proper so I didnot had it. But later on when OP changed it I had no option  then to edit my code. Although now it looks like yours. :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UFpYd/13/):

```
background: url('img.jpg') no-repeat left bottom;
```

or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UFpYd/12/):

```
background: url('img.jpg') no-repeat left bottom fixed;
```

Clarification: [Your fiddle you posted](http://jsfiddle.net/UFpYd/3/) uses `center top` for background image positioning. It should work as you expect if you use `left bottom` (whether `fixed` or not will depend on how you want your image positioned).

Comment: +1 As I got it late after replying initially and you watched the fiddle first! :)

Comment: I was going to post this: http://jsfiddle.net/3Hknp/.  The first one you posted seems to answer his question.

Comment: @JamesWilkins: I agree. A bit baffled why I got a down vote, but oh well, to each his own.

Comment: No idea - I gave you +1. ;)